# How do I generate and use a PGP key on Ubuntu touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, pgp

I'm just starting using Ubuntu touch and of course would like to report every bug I meet. So I sign into to launchpad and like to sing the code of conduct. So I need a pg key...

Is it possible to generate and use a pgp key with Ubuntu touchy?

Comment: I'm still interested in this.. Anyone?